# sql group by clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FollowingUpdates, Line 10
>   Column 'TopicsComplete.TopicCreationDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is after adding these 2 lines, I need to count a separate table rows (the amount of rows not the count of the `topicid`) and include in result any ideas? thanks

```
,COUNT(DISTINCT MC.topicid) AS NewMessagesCount

LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages AS MC ON MC.TopicId = T.TopicId AND MC.userid = @id

@id int = null
,@UserGroupId int = null
AS
SELECT
*
FROM
(SELECT
ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER ( ORDER BY TopicOrder desc
                  , CASE WHEN M.MessageCreationDate > T.TopicCreationDate 
                        THEN M.MessageCreationDate
                        ELSE T.TopicCreationDate
                    END desc )
    AS RowNumber,
T.TopicId, T.TopicTitle, T.TopicShortName, T.TopicDescription, T.TopicCreationDate, T.TopicViews, T.TopicReplies, T.UserId, T.TopicTags, T.TopicIsClose, T.TopicOrder, T.LastMessageId, T.UserName, M.MessageCreationDate, T.ReadAccessGroupId, T.PostAccessGroupId, U.UserGroupId, U.UserPhoto, T.UserFullName ,M.UserId AS MessageUserId ,MU.UserName AS MessageUserName
,COUNT(DISTINCT MC.topicid) AS NewMessagesCount

FROM            TopicsComplete AS T  
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages AS M ON M.TopicId = T.TopicId AND M.MessageId = T.LastMessageId AND M.Active = 1  
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages AS MC ON MC.TopicId = T.TopicId AND MC.userid = @id
                 INNER JOIN Users AS U ON U.UserId = T.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users MU ON MU.UserId = M.UserId

WHERE   EXISTS
(SELECT  * FROM    TopicsComplete
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages AS M ON M.TopicId = T.TopicId AND M.MessageId = T.LastMessageId AND M.Active = 1 INNER JOIN
                   topicfollows AS TF ON T.TopicId != TF.topicid INNER JOIN
                   Users AS U ON U.UserId = T.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   Users AS MU ON MU.UserId = M.UserId
                   WHERE        (T.UserId = @id)

UNION SELECT  * FROM    TopicsComplete
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages AS M ON M.TopicId = T.TopicId AND M.MessageId = T.LastMessageId AND M.Active = 1 INNER JOIN
                        topicfollows AS TF ON T.TopicId = TF.topicid INNER JOIN
                        Users AS U ON U.UserId = T.UserId LEFT JOIN 
                        Users MU ON MU.UserId = M.UserId
                        WHERE        (TF.userid = @id)
      )
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an aggregation function in the `select`, SQL Server quite reasonably assumes that you want to do an aggregation.  All columns not in aggregation functions should then be in the `group by` clause.

In your case, you have `COUNT(DISTINCT MC.topicid) AS NewMessagesCount` in a `select` expression.  All the other columns should be in the `group by`.  There is no `group by`, but you get the error anyway, because one should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have any column not contained in an aggregate (max, min, count, sum, etc.) in the `GROUP BY` clause.